# How to exceute view without DBLink in oracle server

Tags: oracle

I have 2 views, example V1 from Database  DB1 , V2 from database DB2, these 2 database server are remotely configured, I can able to execute these views separately without database link in the respective database server. Now i want to join these views and want to execute it without database link. How do I achieve it?

Comment: You don't.  I assume you are saying that you have a client application (i.e. SQL Developer) that can connect to each database.  If there is no database link, you can't join data between the two short of writing client-side code that fetches all the data from each table and implements join-like logic on the client.  That is generally very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a server (say X) with V1 (pointing at server Y) and V2 (pointing at server Z). Can't you use create GTTs (Global Temporary Tables) with V1 and V2 (this will happen on X) and then perform your join operation on the GTT tables on X using the data from GTT_V1 and GTT_V2? There's a good link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918466/ways-to-avoid-global-temp-tables-in-oracle) about using GTTs. Check out the guidelines section.